# How is C cross platform?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, cross-platform

C language is ultimately compiled to machine specific assembly language. Then how can C be cross platform if every processor has its own assembly language syntax? If I write an operating system kernel in C then how can I make it run across a variety of processors?

Comment: by compiling the C code for different processors/platforms. You can take the same C code and compile it for x86, for ARM, etc. Sure, one specific, compiled binary won't magically run on a different architecture, but that's not what is meant with "cross platform".

Comment: How would you expect an OS kernel to run on different processors? it is *because* there are different processors that the core component of an OS is needed.

Comment: I think the term "portable" is used with C itself more than "cross platform", which means you can recompile/port C source to other platform.Then there are cross-platform libraries for C, which means they deal with the platform details (usually in #ifdef ... way including replacements for platform-specific parts of functionality/API) to make the library API identical on all platforms, but still the compile-for-particular-target step must be there (some platforms allow for "fat" binaries containing multiple executables for different architectures, but those are like different builds concatenated

Comment: with operating system kernel the situation is more specific, as operating system kernel's machine code strongly depends on platform specifics, so it's pretty sure only generic parts of kernel are written in pure C, and there's highly likely some small chunk of platform specific assembly supporting kernel with specialized tasks like context switching, memory unit management, etc... which is completely platform specific.

Comment: All C code isn't portable. If you write an OS, the lowest level hardware stuff that communicates with the specific CPU isn't portable. Only the abstraction layers on top of it. Same goes for drivers etc.

Answer (score 12):

C is portable at the source code level. This means that you can recompile your program in the platform of choice and have your application running there.

You can find the [history of C in the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), for example. At that time, programming was carried out in assembly for each specific machine, so having a high-level (by that time) programming language was a bless: it sped up development and also made possible to port programs from one machine to a new one just by porting the compiler (the C compiler could later be written in C itself, again speeding up the porting process, but that's another story).

Specifically, the idea of porting UNIX between operating systems appeared when they had UNIX running in the PDP-7, and the PDP-11 appeared. Finally, even UNIX's kernel was rewritten in C, so it made the operating system really popular because of the easy porting: there was only the need to write a small amount of assembly for very specific parts of the kernel, so you could have UNIX up and running in a new machine shortly, at least compared to other operating systems of that time.

Answer (score 5):

The language C itself is cross-platform, because you don't directly run C code on machines. The C source code is compiled to assembly, and *assembly* is the platform specific code. The only non cross-platform part are the compilers and the resulting assembly.

In essence, you can use the same C code, with different compilers, to create the specific assembly needed. Since you use the same C source code, its deemed cross-platform.